# How to enable a custom group to django admin panel

Tags: python, django, model, panel, admin

My question is very simple
I created into the models.py a custom user model (it is called Staff)

I would like to know how could i enable this user model called Staff to use the django admin panel
In other words how can i add a Staff to a group created in the admin panel?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what Django version you're using?

Comment: the last 1.4.3, python 2.7, apache 2.2, mysql 5.5

Answer (score 0):

There's a `is_staff` flag for users.  For your `Staff` class, just have

```
class Staff(User):
    is_staff = True
    ---Everything else---
```

Reference source [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User)

If you want to add staff permissions to users, simply click on the `staff` checkbox in the Admin interface.

Comment: my class doesn't belong from the Auth class User, it is a class Created into the file models.py which is called User like Auth class...so it doesn't have the is_staff flag

Comment: Is there a reason why `Staff` does not inherit from `auth.User`?